# Siempre cae al primer if y no se por que

Tags: javascript, formularios

```
function checkSubmit() {

    if (!$('[name="solicitud"]').is(':checked')) {
        console.log('falta seleccionar un servicio');
        statSend = false;
        swal({
        title: 'Para continuar',
        text: 'Seleccione un servicio de la lista..',
        showConfirmButton: true,
        showCloseButton: true,
        })
        return false;

        } else if ($("#monto").val() == "") {
        console.log(' ingrese monto ');
        statSend = false;
          swal({
        title: 'Para continuar',
        text: 'Escriba o seleccione un monto',
        showConfirmButton: true,
        showCloseButton: true,
        })
        return false;

        } else if ($("#titulo").val() == "") {  
        console.log(' ingrese numero ');
        statSend = false;
          swal({
        title: 'Para continuar',
        text: 'Escriba el numero de servicio a recargar',
        showConfirmButton: true,
        showCloseButton: true,
        })
        return false;

        } 
    /* esta validacion esta bien , pero no la segunda...*/


if ($('[name="solicitud"]').val() === "1" && $('#titulo').val().length != 11 ) {    
            console.log('movistar ');
            statSend = false;
              swal({
            title: 'Para continuar',
            text: 'Escriba el numero de servicio a recargar',
            showConfirmButton: true,
            showCloseButton: true,
            })
            return false;

            }
            else  if ($('[name="solicitud"]').val() === "2" && $('#titulo').val().length != 11 ) {  
            console.log('digitel ');
            statSend = false;
              swal({
            title: 'Para continuar',
            text: 'Escriba el numero de servicio a recargar',
            showConfirmButton: true,
            showCloseButton: true,
            })
            return false;

            }   

        swal({
            title: 'Por favor espere!',
            text: 'su solicitud se esta enviando...',
            showConfirmButton: false,
        })
        if (!statSend) {
            statSend = true;
            return true;
        } else {
            alert("El formulario ya se esta enviando...");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Intento hacer funcionar una validacion con javascript y jquery usando el siguiente código que al presionar el boton submit me compruebe bien si el primer radio button fue seleccionado y si el campo titulo tiene una longitud de 11 , esto funciona bien pero mi problema es que trato de mostrar una alerta cuando el valor de mi input radio es igual a 2 y no cumple la longitud minima pero siempre me muestra por consola el primer if...

Comment: No entiendo bien tu pregunta, ¿dices que evalúa siempre esto como verdadero: `if (!$('[name="solicitud"]').is(':checked')) {`? Ahí lo que estás es preguntando **en negativo** si alguno de los elementos cuyo name es `solicitud` está chequeado. O sea, preguntas en negativo algo positivo, combinando `!` con `is checked`. Es una forma confusa de escribir código: *si no es verdad que cualquiera de estos elementos está chequeado*... Si entra en ese bloque es porque la confusa condición se cumple. En la pregunta tampoco se entiende con claridad qué es lo que quieres evaluar en sí.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es la comprobación de `$('[name="solicitud"]').val()` pues esto siempre te devuelve `1`, que es el primer elemento con **nombre="solicitud"**.

Funcionaría bien si el elemento fuera un selector, pero al ser **radio buttons** debes poner: `$('[name="solicitud"]:checked').val()`.

```html
<form >
<input id="titulo" value="12345678901">
<input id="monto" value="10">

<input type="radio" name="solicitud" value="1">movistar</option> 
<input type="radio" name="solicitud" value="2">digitel</option>


<!--select name="solicitud">
    <option value="0">seleccionar</option>
    <option value="1">movistar</option> 
    <option value="2">digitel</option>
</select-->

<input type="submit"  onclick="checkSubmit(); return false;">
</form>

<script>
function checkSubmit() {

    if (!$('[name="solicitud"]').is(':checked')) {
        console.log('falta seleccionar un servicio');
        return false;

    } else if ($("#monto").val() == "") {
        console.log(' ingrese monto ');
        return false;

    } else if ($("#titulo").val() == "") {
        console.log(' ingrese numero ');
        statSend = false;
        return false;

    }


    if ($('[name="solicitud"]:checked').val() === "1" && $('#titulo').val().length != 11) {
        console.log('movistar ');
        return false;

    } else if ($('[name="solicitud"]:checked').val() === "2" && $('#titulo').val().length != 11) {
        console.log('digitel ');
        return false;

    }

    alert("OK");
    return true;
}
</script>
```

> **NOTA**
>   Si usas un selector en vez de "radio buttons" deberás cambiar las comprobaciones del principio del script.

Puedes comprobar el resultado aquí: https://jsfiddle.net/wLf74syu/